# How to update ERC20 token amounts in React Native application quicker?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, blockchain, ethereum

I'm currently updating a cryptocurrency loyalty rewards application written in React Native. The app allows you to "donate" or send tokens to others.

I need to make the token total for a user change in real time after making a donation. My problem is that the Ethereum blockchain takes about 15 seconds to update the totals on-chain, and  currently the reducer is reaching out to the blockchain to grab the wallet balances immediately after the donation. We don't want to make the user sit and watch a spinner for 15 seconds, but we also want the value of their wallet to reflect the transaction immediately.

One solution I can think of is to just add or subtract the proper number of tokens totally within the state of the application, and only reach out to the Ethereum API on loading the application. Is this a suitable approach? What potential issues would I be introducing?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ethereum, you can't get balance on the pending block.

You'll need to be careful deducting user's balance. Token transaction have a higher chance to fail if the gas limit is set incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, we currently have a "refresh" button that will reach out to the blockchain and grab your balance... would you say this is the optimal solution?

Comment: I don't think it is optimal since Coinbase seems to have it figured out...